# Slick slider extra options as data attribute

Tags: custom-data-attribute, slick.js

From documentation the data attribute work like this

```
data-slick='{"dots": true}'
```

For this jquery version

```
$('.one-time').slick({
  dots: true,
});
```

However for more complex settings how does data attribute should be written?Say

```
        $('.center').slick({
         dots: true,
         responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 3
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Simply all settings you can write like {"dots":true,"responsive":{"0":{"breakpoint":1024,"settings":{"slidesToShow":2,"slidesToScroll":1,"dots":true,"arrows":true}},"1":{"breakpoint":600,"settings":{"slidesToShow":1,"slidesToScroll":1,"dots":false,"arrows":false}},"2":{"breakpoint":481,"settings":{"slidesToShow":1,"slidesToScroll":1,"dots":true,"arrows":true}}}}

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same issue, the comment helped, but it didn't work. Found this issue on the github repo : https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1857

So your html markup to have data attribute settings to the slick slider would look like this :

```
<div class="slick-slider" 
     data-slick="{
         "dots": true,
         "responsive": [
        {
          "breakpoint": 768,
          "settings": {
            "arrows": false,
            "centerMode": true,
            "centerPadding": "40px",
            "slidesToShow": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "breakpoint": 480,
          "settings": {
            "arrows": false,
            "centerMode": true,
            "centerPadding": "40px",
            "slidesToShow": 1
          }
        }
      ]
     }">

     <!-- Slides -->

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the data-slick value must be valid json with all settings' attributes enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above comment by Fabian, no trailing commas are allowed in the json.